# How to use git-svn clone to only get the HEAD revision from a Subversion repository?

Tags: git, git-svn

How to use `git svn clone` to only get the HEAD revision from a Subversion repository?

I been trying

```
git svn clone -s http://svn/java/<projectname>
```

but I been getting a lot of empty directory and I tried everything. So know I would like to do a clone of just the head in subversion... Can this be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
git svn clone -s -r HEAD http://svn/java/<projectname>
```

You can also specify a range with `-r 2039:HEAD` if, for example, you want all the revisions from 2039 up to the latest. You might do this if it's really the history prior to 2039 that you object to, rather than everything prior to the current revision.

Comment: i had to remove the "-s" and add change the url to htp://svn/java/<project>/trunk but it looks like it worked for my issues

Answer (score 11):

```
git svn clone -r HEAD http://svn/java/<projectname>
```

Don't forget "-r HEAD". It fetches to the latest revision.